# Fix Label Matching of Django Forms Checkboxes with Multiple Copies of a Form

Tags: django, forms, checkbox, django-forms

I have a Django Form that contains a checkbox:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label="Click me")
```

I have multiple of this form on a page:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <form>
        {{ ExampleForm }}
    </form>
{% endfor }%
```

When I click the label of one of the lower forms, the checkbox in the top form is the one that toggles.  How do I fix the label matching so that the correct instance of the checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize the form, use `auto_id=False`.  Ex:

```
ExampleForm(auto_id=False)
```